# Android set drawable

Tags: android

I'm trying to set an image dynamically with drawable so it changes accordingly

xml (with default "home" image)

```
<ImageView     
android:id="@+id/revimage"   
android:layout_width="40dip"
android:layout_height="30dip"
android:onClick="home"
android:src="@drawable/home"/>
```

java

```
if("rating".equals(var)){

    findViewById(R.id.revimage).setIcon(R.drawable.info);

}else if("show".equals(var)){

    findViewById(R.id.revimage).setIcon(R.drawable.view);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
if("rating".equals(var)) {
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.revimage)).setImageResouce(R.drawable.info);
}
else if("show".equals(var)) {
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.revimage)).setImageResouce(R.drawable.view);
}
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29)

Comment: Getting error: The method setImageResource(int) is undefined for the type view

Comment: I updated my answer. By the way it would be better to simply create an `ImageView imageView` variable, initialise it in `onCreate` and then refer to it in the block of code you posted, rather than doing `findViewById` every time.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code..

```
imageViewid.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourimage);
```